# Adjective and Noun Placement

Tags: adjectives, syntactic-analysis, phrasing

Is it better to say "We rescued the five people trapped" or "We rescued the five trapped people"? And why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to say is that a rescue of five trapped people was effected, then I'd go with *We rescued the five trapped people.*

*We rescued the five people trapped* sounds like you've left something off at the end.

> - We rescued the five people trapped in the rubble.
> - We rescued the five people trapped by the rising water.
> - We rescued the five people trapped in the burning building.
> - We rescued the five people trapped. (?)